# ctest complains "No test configuration file found!"

Tags: cmake, debian, ctest

With **CMake** I try to execute a simple test using **CTest**. I have this configuration all in one directory (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}):

```
~$ cat hello.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello world\n";
    return(0);
}

~$ cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(TEST_CTEST)

enable_testing()
add_executable(test_ctest hello.cpp)
add_test(my_test ./build/test_ctest)
```

Then I execute:

```
~$ rm -rf Testing/ build/
~$ cmake -S . -B build
~$ cmake --build build
~$ ./build/test_ctest
hello world

~$ ctest
*********************************
No test configuration file found!
*********************************
Usage

  ctest [options]
```

The only hint I have found in other Q&A is to place `enable_testing()` into the root `CMakeLists.txt`. I feel like I just missed a little thing, but I can't find what.

How do I run a test with CTest?

Comment: You need to call `ctest` from **build** directory. Exactly this directory contains configuration file which `ctest` wants to read.

Comment: @Tsyvarev As I feared it is only a minor matter... Please make your comment an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer from @Tsyvarev is not entierly true. You have to execute `ctest` not only from the build directory, but also from the relative folder inside your build-directory, where `enable_testing()` was called relatively to the `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` directory.

So, e.g. when the `CMakeLists.txt`, which calls `enable_testing()` is located at `proj/tests` and your build directory is `proj/build`. Then you have to run `ctest` in `proj/build/tests`.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I haven't noticed this because I `enable_testing()` in the root `CMakeLists.txt` that enables testing in my `build/` directory. But anyway it's good to know. Btw. what do you mean with `CMakeFile.txt`? Isn't it `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: Handy answer! When using VS2019 to build (after configuring with cmake), the CMake test file is located in `build/VS2019`, **not** in `build`.

Answer (score 9):

The macro `enable_testing()` creates ctest configuration file in the build directory. For find this file, `ctest` needs to be run from that **build** directory.

Running `ctest` from the source directory has no sense, as it doesn't see results of CMake (unless you do in-source builds).

Comment: "unless you do in-source builds"... which you absolutely should not.

Comment: Starting with CMake 3.20, you can also run `ctest --test-dir /path/to/tests` according to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644741/run-ctest-from-different-directory-than-build-directory-used-by-cmake